# JInternalFrame showing popup menu when JTextArea has Ctrl + Space pressed

Tags: java, keyevent, jinternalframe

I am implementing an autocomplete function, but I'm having problems with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, while other combinations work.

My problem is the following

by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> the following Popup Menu is shown, and I do not know how to disable it.

[image: popMenu]

This is the event code that is executed.

```
KeyAdapter keyAdapter = new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
           public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
           {
               AWTKeyStroke ak = AWTKeyStroke.getAWTKeyStrokeForEvent(e);
               if(ak.equals(AWTKeyStroke.getAWTKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE,InputEvent.CTRL_MASK))||ak.equals(AWTKeyStroke.getAWTKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_T,InputEvent.CTRL_MASK)))
               {
                   mostraMenuTeclado(e);
               }
           }
    };
```

the event is added to a JTextArea in a JInternalFrame